# How to select a row in a continuously updating table?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

guys.I'm working on a GUI for controlling some robots.
There is a table which shows the current states data about that robot.And the table is updated periodically from the data in the test server.When the updating was not connected it was easy to select a row in the table and save the selected row's data.However,when the server is connected, it becomes impossible to select a row(when u click on the row,the selected row will be highlighted only in a flash and gone).I try to use some print method to see what has happened inside, it seems that the slots will not be implemented when the updating is running.And the updating will also deselect the row frequently.I'm considering block the updating when I manually select a row,then automatically select the same row with a piece of logic and the selectRow() method.Do u have any suggestion for how to block the updating or another way to deal with this problem?

1.updating method, which work as a slot in a Gui Controller class to manage input

```
def tbRobotChanged(self, currentCell):

    # get the selected cell's index from currentCell,Implement the Slot method
    tablemodel= currentCell.model() 
    #get the model of the currentcell
    firstColumn = tablemodel.index(currentCell.row(),0)
    #change it to the first column in the row with the robot name

    self.statusBar().showMessage("Selected Robot is " +
                                 firstColumn.data().toString())
    self.selected_robot = int(firstColumn.data().toString())
    # show the selected robot name in the statusbar
```

2.table definition ,this is part of a Gui class which define the main window:

```
def initRobotsFrame(self, rf):
    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
    self.robot_table = QtGui.QTableView()
    self.table_header = ['Robot', 'PosX', 'PosY', 'Heading']
    tm = RobotTableModel([[0, 0, 0, 2],[1, 1,2,4]],
                         self.table_header)
    self.robot_table.setModel(tm)
    vh = self.robot_table.verticalHeader()
    vh.setVisible(False)
    self.robot_table.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.robot_table.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy(
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum,
        QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum))
    hbox.addWidget(self.robot_table)
    self.selected_robot = 0

    block_true=GUIController.robot_data.blockSignals(True)
    GUIController.robot_data.blockSignals(block_true)
    # select table by row instead of by cell:
    self.robot_table.setSelectionBehavior(
        QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)        
    # set the signal and slot using selectionModel:
    self.robot_table.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(
        self.tbRobotChanged) 
    self.robot_table.selectionModel().currentRowChanged.connect(
        self.updateActiveRobot)
    # implement a statusbar to test the table selection functionality:
    self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")         
    rf.setLayout(hbox)
```

3.slot to get the selected row's data:

```
def tbRobotChanged(self, currentCell):

    # get the selected cell's index from currentCell,Implement the Slot method
    tablemodel= currentCell.model() 
    #get the model of the currentcell
    firstColumn = tablemodel.index(currentCell.row(),0)
    #change it to the first column in the row with the robot name

    self.statusBar().showMessage("Selected Robot is " +
                                 firstColumn.data().toString())
    self.selected_robot = int(firstColumn.data().toString())
    # show the selected robot name in the statusbar
```

Comment: How do you update the model? Unless you're resetting the model at each update, selection should persist in the view.

Comment: @Avaris I've found the cure, if the resetting model runs periodicaly,the emitting of siganals and the selectionModel(some selection fundamental settings) will all have to be looped accordingly

Comment: So you're resetting the model. If it's not a _massive_ update, reset is not a nice option.

Comment: @Avaris yeah, maybe I should change that since it's a Gui controlling some robots with embbeded system,anything faster is very beneficial here. Thx for your kind help:)